# Where exactly does a jsp page get deployed when run via Netbeans or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

In Netbeans, I created a new default web application project which had an `index.jsp`. In `Tools > Servers` I had already pointed Netbeans to the place I had extracted Tomcat (C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42).

I ran the program, the browser opened and the `index.jsp` file was displayed.

What I don't understand is, that the `index.jsp` file was not automatically copied to the Tomcat folder and it still worked. I thought that for a file to work, it had to be copied to the `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF` folder.

1. How does Netbeans manage to execute the `index.jsp` file without copying it to the Tomcat folder?
2. When I run the program in Netbeans and Eclipse, it shows that it is starting the Tomcat server. Is it starting the same server in `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42` or is it creating a separate 'virtual' kind of an instance of the server and running it in the Netbeans/Eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat creates a separate instance of the Tomcat server that is run in the eclipse workspace (not sure about Netbeans). So there are the server.xml, catalina.policy, tomcat-users.xml, and web.xml files that get created separately. More info in the [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#When_I_create_my_first_Tomcat_server.2C_why_is_a_Servers_project_created_in_my_workspace.3F).

> When I create my first Tomcat server, why is a Servers project
>   created in my workspace?
>
> The Servers project is created, along with a subfolder associated with
>   the Tomcat server, to hold copies of the server.xml, catalina.policy,
>   tomcat-users.xml, and web.xml files for that Tomcat server. In WTP
>   2.0.x and later, catalina.properties is included as well. This makes is easier to make modifications to those files. It also allows these
>   files to be "working copies", separate from the copies that are found
>   in the conf directory of the instance location. This avoids the
>   possibility of interfering with a running Tomcat server if
>   modifications are made to the files in the Servers project while the
>   server is running.
>
> This Servers project must remain open for Tomcat servers to function
>   properly. Be aware that use of the Close Unrelated Projects command
>   may unintentionally close the Servers project. Reopen the Servers
>   project if this occurs.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to know that Tomcat has two configurable directories:

- **`CATALINA_HOME`**, the directory where you chose to install Tomcat. e. g. `c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0`. Tomcat uses this variable to find its internal classes and libraries.
- **`CATALINA_BASE`** the directory of the configuration files and directories, such as the web application directories. If `CATALINA_BASE` isn't set, it defaults to the value of `CATALINA_HOME`. e. g. `C:\Users\JVerstry\.netBeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base`

---

#### NetBeans

In NetBeans, you will see that in:

[image: Tomcat Configuration]

NetBeans copies the files to the *Catalina Base* directory for deploy. This directory is in the user profile directory.

---

#### eclipse

In eclipse, you will see that in:

[image: Tomcat metadata]

eclipse copies the files for deploy, by default, in the `.metadata` directory of the *workspace*.

Comment: My catalina base folder points to `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42` but when I created my servlet project, the `NameHandler.class` file got created in `F:\Programming\Java\HelloWeb\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\org\mypackage\hello`. I searched the tomcat directory, and the `.class` file wasn't there. Nor was any trace of my HelloWeb project. So my question persists, as to how the program works even if the `.class` file does not actually get deployed in the tomcat directory?

Comment: Print the next: `String realPath = request.getRealPath("");`. Where is it?

Comment: `request.getRealPath` is deprecated, so I tried `String strAbsolutePath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");String realpath = request.getServletPath();` and the result was `F:\Programming\Java\HelloWeb\build\web\`

Comment: Sorry about that. And what going on? Did you find the file that you are looking for?

Comment: Repeating my question again: The file is in HelloWeb project's folder. I'm asking how it is working by being in that folder, without getting deployed in the tomcat folder which is in the C drive?

Comment: NetBeans copy the file to a third folder. In this way, does not affect the project folder or files Tomcat.

Comment: I'm aware of it being copied into another folder. The question is, how does it work in that folder? I guess I'll ask on the Netbeans mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do deployment task easily using Netbeans or Eclipse . Follow
>   these steps.

1. first make your project bug/error free.
2. if your project is running properly then right click on root folder
   from project list of netBeans or Eclipse .
3. Click on clean and build option.
4. A folder named Dist will be created into your project directory you
   can view using Explorer the dist folder contains a projectname.WAR
   file.
5. Now open your tomcat web server click on "Manage Apps" login with
   proper credential.
6. Go to the "WAR file to deploy" section.
7. Brows our war file and click on deploy button.
8. Now you can see your application in Applications list.
9. Click on your application.

> Enjoy :)